# how many sites powered by codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

help me please!!!

Comment: Are you going to die if you don't know the answer?

Comment: twenty seven and a half, closed!!!!!

Comment: 3,472,943. Give or take a few million.

Comment: Not really sure if there *is* a way to actually answer your question - after all, not everyone puts "powered by codeigniter" into their footer, and CI doesn't really have a distinctive signature when seen from the outside.

Comment: From the horse's mouth: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Applications_Using_Code_Igniter/ but there could be many more undeclared ones as Piskvor mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least [242](http://codeigniter.com/projects/).. :P